# ubuntu 14.04 - Samba - How to share from another drive?

Tags: networking, permissions, samba

I am pretty much done setting up my home media computer but I am stuck on one of my last tasks. I am new to linux/Ubuntu so I have a lot to learn about permissions and what not and I'm pretty sure that is what I'm tied up on at this time. So I followed this guide [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/samba-fileserver.html) on how to set samba up and it worked perfectly.

Now I am attempting to share a folder on another drive located at /media/media/Big Drive/Music with no luck. I have spent probably around 8 or so hours over the last 3 days and I keep failing miserably. The folder that I setup using the guide will let me access it and move files in and out, just like you would expect but the other folder I am attempting to share will let me see it on the network folder but I can't even open it. Windows just gives me a network error telling me it cannot access it. How would I go about fixing this?

Since I am new please give me step by step instructions or I may get confused :/ Thanks in advance for all your help

Comment: What is media/media? On my machine I have media/Ilan, i.e. media/user name. Inside ilan is the disk on key, or whatever.

Comment: I used the user name media since it is going to be my media machine.

Comment: I think I found what the problem might be. This is a NTFS formatted drive from when I had windows on my computer. Still not really sure how to solve my issue but I think that is the reason I have an issue in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the permissions issue. What actually you should do is check your permissions on /media/media/Big Drive/Music:

```
ls -l /media/media/Big Drive/Music
```

it could like in your case as this: drwx------- or something like that then proceed like following:

```
sudo chmod w+r /media/media/Big Drive/Music
```

but if you want only just let people read files (listen only to music) and not allowing them to write/modify run this:

```
sudo chmod 774 /media/media/Big Drive/Music
```

Comment: usefull tool for permissions: http://permissions-calculator.org/